# Finding element in SAS/IML

Tags: sas

In SAS/IML I have defined a character variable:

```
var1 = "usernames";
```

Previously in the code I defined usernames as a matrix:

```
usernames = {bill george fred, matthew john mark, katie, jack, lucy};
```

How can I manipulate this so that when I type

```
print var1;
```

I get the usernames matrix as output?

Comment: Change the name of usernames variable.

Comment: No offense but just a suggestion. Judging from these IML basic questions you recently ask, I think you should first go to an online tutorial resources of IML like SAS official site and learn the basic. It will help you solve these problems faster.

Comment: I've read through all the SAS/IML documentation on the SAS website, it really does provide no assistance whatsoever when answering these basic questions.

Comment: I don't know much IML, but I suspect that @RobbieLiu's suggestion is a good one. Have you really ready all 1037 pages of the IML documentation? (http://support.sas.com/documentation/onlinedoc/91pdf/sasdoc_91/iml_ug_7306.pdf) I've found that the examples in the SAS documentation are a great way to learn. Again, don't take offense. If I knew the answer, I'd share it. Just trying to offer alternatives.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the OP wants to reference the contents of what the var1 variable "points to." Use the VALUE function:

```
   usernames = {bill george fred, matthew john mark, katie jack lucy};
   var1 = "usernames";
   print (value(var1));
```

The [VALUE function](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/imlug/64248/HTML/default/viewer.htm#imlug_langref_sect322.htm) and the [VALSET call](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/imlug/64248/HTML/default/viewer.htm#imlug_langref_sect321.htm) can be used for this kind of [indirect assignment and retrieval in SAS/IML](http://blogs.sas.com/content/iml/2011/03/23/indirect-assignment-how-to-create-and-use-matrices-named-x1-x2-xn/).

Answer (score 0):

First of all, defining the username matrix is wrong. it should be

```
  usernames = {bill george fred, matthew john mark, katie  jack lucy};
```

then

```
  var1 = usernames;
```